# RestKit no longer working ( symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 )

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

So I have an app that I have been developing over the past 2 years. This app uses restkit. All of a sudden it stopped compiling. Here is what I am getting.

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKConnectionTestExpectation", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libRestKit.a(RKMappingTest.o)
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKPropertyMappingTestExpectation", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in libRestKit.a(RKMappingTest.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: RKMappingTest is used for unit testing. If you build for running then check why do you include unit tests classes.

Comment: What did you change before this happened? Xcode version, project settings, RestKit version? What type of build are you doing? How is RK integrated? Why are you compiling RK tests?

Comment: I ran out of room on my hard drive so I deleted the old ios 7.0, 7.1 updates that run about 1GM each.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the submodule and using cocoapods then recompiled and it worked.